# MySql non-greedy regex

Tags: mysql, regex

I have the following text '`ab{0}c`' which should be considered equal to another text if the only difference is in the text inside the curly brackets. eg. `ab{hello}c == ab{0}c`

The regex expression to do this is `ab\\{(.*?)\\}c`

The only problem is that when I try to execute this regex with the REGEXP MYSql function it is giving me the following error:

```
Error Code: 1139
Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp
```

The problem is the '`?`', if this is removed from the expression, the regex works fine but the problem is that the expression becomes greedy which will then match also `ab{0}c{1}` which I don't want.

Any ideas on how I could solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your `.` for a `[^}]` (negated character class, matches what isn't a `}`) and you won't need the non-greediness.

```
^ab\\{([^}]*)\\}c$
```

Comment: The problem is that with this expression the text ab{a}c{b} is also considered equal to ab{0}c which should not as it had different amounts of curly brackets.

Comment: You'd have the same problem with the non-greedy modifier. I edited the answer with anchors to match beginning and end of string.